# Start with Firefox addons and iframes

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, add-on, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to create my firefox addon. I want to call a javascript that changes the src of the iframes.

I dont know how to build an addon that calls my function on **BEFORE PAGE LOAD**. Only I got is the main.js. I tried to insert *alert('hello');* into it, but nothing happens. Is there any useful tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is the Addon SDK documentation:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/

In particular there is a getting started tutorial:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/dev-guide/addon-development/getting-started.html

While it may not solve your particular problem with controlling iframe urls, it will give you a better idea how the SDK works.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed one the most desirable things is get the DOM loaded. So generally we must wait until page is loaded (DOM).

That's why listener as the following are used so much:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){}, false);
appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function docLoader(e){}, true);
```

So just call any function that you build. It will run before any page load.

---

To work in FF addon development helps a lot always make searches prefixing MDN (Mozilla Developer Network). Besides I recommend you read all this [MDN: XUL School Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School). It start like this:

> XUL School is a comprehensive add-on development tutorial, focusing on
>   Firefox extension development. It is recommended that you read through
>   all of it at least once. While Firefox changes rapidly, the content in
>   this tutorial should be up to date and valid.

Comment: I main.js code of the addon is look like this: function docLoader()
{
    alert('loaded');
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){alert('loaded');}, false);
appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function docLoader() {}, true); But nothing happens...